# Show that $A_4$ is a subgroup of $A_5.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $A_n$ denote the alternating group of even permutations of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

Is $A_4$  a subgroup of $A_5$?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you want when checking if a subset is a subgroup: closure and inverses.

(More formally, $H < G$ if for all $h_1, h_2 \in H$ we have $h_1h_2 \in H$, and for all $h \in H$, we have $h^{-1} \in H$. Some people like to condense this into one criterion and say $H$ is a subgroup if $h_1h_2^{-1} \in H$ but I find this less useful in practice.)

$A_4$ is certainly a subset of $A_5$. We already know $A_4$ is closed under the operation that $A_5$ has because that's how the group is defined. We also already know $A_4$ contains all the inverses of its elements. So yes, it's a subgroup.

Comment: Technically the subset -part is not immediate. The elements of $A_4$ are functions from $\{1,2,3,4\}$ to itself, and the elements of $A_5$ are functions from $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ to itself. There is a way of extending the former type of objects to those of the latter type in such a way that the "type of function" is preserved (biijection, even,...), but ...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think it is pretty immediate here because it is clear that every element $\sigma\in S_n$ can also be viewed as a permutation of $n+1$ letters simply by setting $\sigma(n+1)=n+1$, this is the natural identification

Comment: @CurtisW: Agreed. I did say "technically" :-). Depends on whether the asker has been exposed to the idea before. I've seen students who had problems with less immediate identification maps, say when we have $A_4$ acting on $\{2,3,4,5\}$ instead of $\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Comment: Of course, the technicality is something that should be addressed : ) especially with beginners.

Answer (score 0):

It is. It can be proven directly. Consider $G = \{ (), (1,2)(3,4), (1,3)(2,4), (1,4)(2,3), (1,2,3), (1,3,2), (1,2,4), (1,4,2), (1,3,4), (1,4,3), (2,3,4), (2,4,3) \}$. Then element $5 \in A_5$ is fixed by $G$. $G$ is fairly clearly a subgroup of $A_5$ (if it is not clear to you, prove it). We can also prove isomorphism between $G$ and $A_4$.

Comment: Although it is true that the proof can be done by brute force, I think it is just more insightful to note that every even permutation of $S_n$ is still an even permutation of $S_{n+1}$ (where we identify $\sigma\in S_n$ with the permutation that agrees with $\sigma$ on the first $n$ letters and acts as the identity on $n+1$.) Since we already know $A_n$ is a group, this automatically gives that $A_n$ is a subgroup of $A_{n+1}$

Comment: I agree of course. The ability to generalize is important. However, sometimes a concrete picture is nice too, especially when material is new.

Comment: Yes absolutely! Both methods have their merits. The "abstract method" here has the advantage that it makes the general result more clear, while the direct proof makes it more explicit to those less familiar sometimes. For someone new to group theory maybe it would be good to try the direct proof first and then generalize- especially if they are not too comfortable with $S_n$ yet.